# Regex Match Exact Number at beginning (like 99 but not 999)

Tags: php, regex

This should be a simple task, but searching for it all day I still can't figure out what I'm missing

I'm trying to open a file using PHP's glob() that begins with a *specific* number

Example filenames in a directory:

```
1.txt
123.txt
10 some text.txt
100 Some Other Text.txt
```

The filenames always begin with a unique number (which is what i need to use to find the right file) and are optionally followed by a space and some text and finally the .txt extension

My problem is that no matter what I do, if i try to match the number 1 in the example folder above it will match every file that begins with 1, but I need to open *only* the file that starts with *exactly* 1, no matter what follows it, whether it be a space and text or just .txt

Some example regex that *does not* succeed at the task:

```
filepath/($number)*.txt
filepath/([($number)])( |*.?)*.txt
filepath/($number)( |*.?)*.txt
```

I'm sure there's a very simple solution to this... If possible I'd like to avoid loading every single file into a PHP array and using PHP to check every item for the one that begins with only the exact number, when surely regex can do it in a single action

A bonus would be if you also know how to turn the optional text between the number and the extension into a variable, but that is entirely optional as it's my next task after I figure this one out

Comment: `/^\d\D/` would match a string that starts with a single digit, followed by a non-digit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want OP:

```
$regex = '/' . $number . '[^0-9][\S\s]+/';
```

This matches the number, then any character that isn't a number, then any other characters. If the number is 1, this would match:

```
1.txt
1abc.txt
1 abc.txt
1_abc.txt
1qrx.txt
```

But it would not match:

```
1
12.txt
2.txt
11.txt
1.
```

Comment: The idea behind this method lead me to the answer for my particular case; matching the desired number, then NOT matching any additional numbers, and then whatever else comes after, brilliant! I found I was able to use [!0-9] in glob() for this to avoid additional numbers after the desired one had been found, so simple yet so perfect, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

The Regex you want to use is: `^99(\D+\.txt)$`

```
$re = "/^99(\D+\.txt)$/";
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

This will match:

```
99.txt
99files.txt
```

but not:

```
199.txt
999.txt
99
99.txt.xml
99filesoftxt.dat
```

The `( )` around the `\D+.txt` will create a capturing group which will contain your file name.

Comment: That \D+ works like magic, I'm so glad to know about it now, thanks a lot! Unfortunately for some reason ^99(\D+\.txt)$ didn't work for me for the particular situation I was asking about, but it worked on a similar case, thanks :) using it to understand regex better now

Comment: The `^` means it must start the string, `(` and ')' create a capturing group for the file name and place it in $matches (that was the 2nd part of your question). `\D+` is any non-numeric characters, but the + means it doesn't require any characters in that spot (letting it match 99.txt) then `\.txt$` means look for .txt which ends the file, so 99file.txt matches but 99file.txts doesn't. Hope that helps!

Comment: Ohhhh... that's freaking brilliant, I get it now, I was about to waste a lot of performance on matching the rest of the string with another function, but using what you just taught me that'd be unnecessary, thanks a lot! :D I thought $matches only appeared from specific functions like preg_replace_callback() where I thought $matches was one of the main purposes of the function, glad I was wrong as it'll come in very handy in a lot of places I use regex via PHP! This is great! Looks like a simple (\D+) is gonna replace an entire folder-reading function for me now, thanks!! ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^10\D.*txt$
  ^--- use the number you want
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/sM3bU0/2)**

[image]

For intance:

```
$re = "/^10\\D.*txt$/m"; 
$str = "1.txt\n123.txt\n10 some text2.txt\n100 Some Other2 Text.txt"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
// will match only 10 some text.txt
```

Comment: what if `100 Some Other Text2.txt`

Comment: Assuming the magic number is 123, this won't match `123 foo4.txt` and will match `123 whatever.xml`, neither of which is what OP wants.

Comment: This is wonderful, and you also gave me an excellent resource to test out any future regex, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<?php
    function findFileWithNumericPrefix($filepath, $prefix)
    {   
        if (($dir = opendir($filepath)) === false) {
            return false;
        }

        while (($filename = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
            if (preg_match("/^$prefix\D/", $filename) === 1) {
                closedir($dir);
                return $filename;
            }
        }

        closedir($dir);

        return false;
    }

    $file = findFileWithNumericPrefix('/base/file/path', 1);                

    if ($file !== false) {
        echo "Found file: $file";
    }
?>
```

With your example directory listing, the result is:

```
Found file: 1.txt
```

Comment: Wow! Just, wow! This is mighty useful for the for the rest of my function, thanks a lot! :D